# Get email from xml using SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table in SQL with the following columns and data:

- First_name  is Joe
- Last_Name is  Smith
- Zipcode is 12345
- Join_date is 05012011
- xmldata is `<data>Idontknow_noidea@noemail.net</data>`

How do I write a select query in SQL that will extract the email in a SQL query so my results can look like:

```
Joe,  Smith, 12345, 05012011, Idontknow_noidea@noemail.net
```

for the First_name, Last_Name, Zipcode, Join_date and email headers respectively?

Answer (score 0):

Look at XQuery, which is made to work with the xml datatype specifcially.

Here is a good explanation (quick and dirty):
http://www.brokenwire.net/bw/Programming/125/querying-xml-fields-using-t-sql

And here is something a little more in-depth (from MSDN):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345122%28SQL.90%29.aspx